# Kotlin - Easiest way to blink text (visible / invisible)

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, blink

I'm trying to blink a text (based on a previous button click) but my App crashes after 1000ms/2000ms.

I have tried to create a thread but I'm not sure if it is the easiest way. Can someone help me?

This is my current code:

```
fun toggleBlinkCounterUI() {

        /*var handler: Handler = Handler();
        Thread(Runnable() {
            override fun run() {
                var timeToBlink: Long = 1000;
                    Thread.sleep(timeToBlink)

                handler.post(Runnable() {
                    fun run() {
                        if (binding.exerciseTimer.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
                            binding.exerciseTimer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        } else {
                            binding.exerciseTimer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                        toggleBlinkCounterUI();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();*/

        /*val thread = Thread {
            var timeToBlink: Long = 1000;

            while (1 == 1) {
                Thread.sleep(timeToBlink)
                if (binding.exerciseTimer.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
                    binding.exerciseTimer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                } else {
                    binding.exerciseTimer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
        thread.start()*/
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Handler) and make use of its [postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Handler#postdelayed) method. As you want to change the UI you need to use the main looper: `val uiCallbackHandler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`. Apart from that you need two more things:

1. Create [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) that will define your UI alternation logic
2. Post delayed with the 1000 millis you currently use for thread sleeping.

Making use of combination of my suggestions and your code (I also made it a bit more Kotlin-ish):

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val switchVisibilityRunnable = Runnable {
  binding.exerciseTimer.isVisible = !binding.exerciseTimer.isVisible
  handler.postDelayed(switchVisibilityRunnable, 1000)
}
handler.post(switchVisibilityRunnable)
```

Comment: Could you detail it a little bit? I have tried a code like that and it is not working, I'll update original post with commented code. It is not entering run functions. Override doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Clandes you are new to StackOverflow, but apparently know how to get help: if you post your code, we will be able to help you. Give me a sec, i will add a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @Clandes My update is in now. Obviously you will need to work out some break condition, but this should suffice for the basics of `Handler` usage.

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks good. I will try it ASAP.

Comment: Thank you very much (again), I adapted my code and it works. I'll post here right now.